# Execute a batch file from HTML page

Tags: html, batch-file

How can I execute a .bat file directly from webpage written in HTML format?

*(This question was originally tagged with [java].)*

Comment: what does this have to do with java?

Comment: I sincerely hope (*and pretty strongly believe*) that it is **IMPOSSIBLE**

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you want to do, but it sounds to me like it's impossible.

If you want the .bat file to be executed **on the server** on which the web page is hosted, then you can't solve it using plain old HTML. You need a scripting language like PHP or similar.

If you want to execute the .bat file **on the client**, that is, on the host running the browser, it is definitely impossible. (Imagine the consequences if any random site could start executing system-commands on your computer.)

---

Since you've tagged it with Java, I'll assume you had some sort of Java-applet (or perhaps javascript) solution in mind. This doesn't change anything. Both applets and scripts are executed in a sandboxed environment, and there is no way you can execute .bat files using these techniques.

Comment: Thankx, I hava done it indirectly, by opening the dialogbox containing the .bat file n then executing it from there with the help of javascript.